# Azure Storage Account SLA vs Durability

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Based on Microsoft's documentation the [SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/storage/v1_5/) for storage account is defined as,

> We guarantee that at least **99.9%** (99% for Cool Access Tier) of the time, we will successfully process requests to write data to Locally Redundant Storage (LRS), Zone Redundant Storage (ZRS), and Geo Redundant Storage (GRS) Accounts and Read Access-Geo Redundant Storage (RA-GRS) Accounts

Similarly looking at Azure Storage Redundancy section, for [ZRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#zone-redundant-storage)

> ZRS offers durability for Azure Storage data objects of at least **99.9999999999%** (12 9's) over a given year.
> With ZRS, your data is still accessible for both read and write operations even if a zone becomes unavailable

Am I correct in assuming that the Storage account(with ZRS) is available(R/W) 12 9's over the period of a year and not 3 9's?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage in the SLA doc is referring to Availability(it means that system is up, data can be accessed), and in ZRS doc is referring to Durability(it means that no data is lost or corruption when failure occurs).

The read/write operation depends on the Availability. So for Storage account(with ZRS), it is 3 9's. You can also refer to this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#durability-and-availability-parameters) for more details.